# Unit test iOS with Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, jenkins

I'm trying to automate my iOS projects with jenkins. 
However I'm running into a problem with the project I want to test with jenkins.

The project is named `ttt` and is using cocoapods so it has a workspace named `ttt` as well.

Looking at the schemes the following exist inside the project.
[image]

I've followed [this](http://mmorejon.github.io/en/blog/continuous-integration-jenkins-ios9-xcode/) tutorial.

the settings I've done are as follows
[image]

[image]

[image]

When I try to run it it will get stuck right here!

```
Going to invoke xcodebuild:, scheme: ttt, sdk: DEFAULT, workspace: ttt, configuration: Debug, clean: NO, archive:NO, symRoot: DEFAULT, configurationBuildDir: DEFAULT, codeSignIdentity: DEFAULT
[lbp-iOS] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme ttt -workspace ttt.xcworkspace -configuration Debug build test -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=10.1"
```

When I remove the `ttt` from the workspace field I get the following error

```
Going to invoke xcodebuild:, scheme: ttt, sdk: DEFAULT, project: DEFAULT, configuration: Debug, clean: NO, archive:NO, symRoot: DEFAULT, configurationBuildDir: DEFAULT, codeSignIdentity: DEFAULT
[lbp-iOS] $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme ttt -configuration Debug build
xcodebuild: error: The project named "ttt" does not contain a scheme named "ttt". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the project.
Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
Recording test results
```

Comment: What do you mean "stuck"? It just sits at that `Going to invoke xcodebuild ...` line forever?

Comment: @kpsharp yeah it just sits there. I have let it run for 30min but it won't move from that point. I would rather see an error then that honestly lol

Comment: That's probably an issue with the Xcode Integration plugin, then. You could reach out to them to try to get it fixed. Alternatively, you could write bash scripts to run the Xcode command line tools that are packaged with Xcode and just run the scripts as part of the Jenkins plan.

Comment: Same thing happening to me.  Did you every find a solution?

Comment: @greg I did I'll post an answer for this when I get near my laptop in a few

Comment: @greg Posted an answer hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright so why it wasn't working had to do with the fact that the scheme wasn't actually sent to git.
You need to specify this inside of your xcode project otherwise it won't even show up as a file that you can commit.

To do this go to `xcode > Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes`
You'll see a screen with all the schemes in your project make sure you tick the box under `Shared` for all the schemes you want to use in Jenkins like this.

[image]

Push this to your git and try it again. It should work now.

Comment: @greg no problem glad it worked. I would advice you to take a look at fastlane that's what I currently use integrated in jenkins ofcourse